# Type mismatch when cloning the lines of the trait BufRead

Tags: types, rust, buffer, clone, lines

To get better with Rust, I've decided to implement a simple lexer that analyzes some documents line by line.

As I have to iterate at least two times over the lines of the trait `BufRead`, I am cloning the lines of my `BufRead` but I get the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::io::Lines<T> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == &_`
  --> <anon>:18:23
   |
18 |     let lines = lines.cloned();
   |                       ^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>`
   = note:    found type `&_

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::io::Lines<T> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == &_`
```

I understand what the error is, but based on the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3AWrite%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3A%7BBufRead%2C%20BufReader%2C%20Lines%2C%20Read%7D%3B%0A%0Apub%20struct%20DocumentMetadata%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20language%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20fn%20analyze%3CT%3A%20BufRead%3E(document%3A%20T)%20-%3E%20Result%3CDocumentMetadata%2C%20()%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20lines%20%3D%20document.lines()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20language%20%3D%20guess_language(%26lines)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20more%20lexical%20analysis%20based%20on%20document%20language%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(DocumentMetadata%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20language%3A%20language%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20guess_language%3CT%3A%20BufRead%3E(lines%3A%20%26Lines%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20String%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20lines%20%3D%20lines.cloned()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20line%20in%20lines%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20line%20%3D%20line.unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Try%20to%20guess%20language%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%22en%22.to_string()%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Btest%5D%0Afn%20it_guesses_document_language()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20document%20%3D%20String%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20writeln!(%26mut%20document%2C%20%22%23%20language%3A%20en%22).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20document%20%3D%20BufReader%3A%3Anew(document.as_str().as_bytes())%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20match%20analyze(document)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(metadata)%20%3D%3E%20assert_eq!(%22en%22.to_string()%2C%20metadata.language)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(_)%20%3D%3E%20panic!()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0), how can I tell the compiler what the `Item` of the `Iterator` should be so it can correctly cast the type?

```
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Lines, Read};

pub struct DocumentMetadata {
    language: String,
    // ...
}

pub fn analyze<T: BufRead>(document: T) -> Result<DocumentMetadata, ()> {
    let lines = document.lines();
    let language = guess_language(&lines);

    // Do more lexical analysis based on document language

    Ok(DocumentMetadata {
        language: language,
        // ...
    })
}

fn guess_language<T: BufRead>(lines: &Lines<T>) -> String {
    let lines = lines.cloned();
    for line in lines {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        // Try to guess language
    }
    "en".to_string()
}

#[test]
fn it_guesses_document_language() {
    let mut document = String::new();
    writeln!(&mut document, "# language: en").unwrap();
    let document = BufReader::new(document.as_str().as_bytes());

    match analyze(document) {
        Ok(metadata) => assert_eq!("en".to_string(), metadata.language),
        Err(_) => panic!(),
    }
}
```

For unit testing purpose, I am building a buffer with a `String` but in a normal usage I read it from a `File`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) definition:

```
fn cloned<'a, T>(self) -> Cloned<Self> 
    where Self: Iterator<Item=&'a T>, 
          T: 'a + Clone
```

And the implementation of `Iterator` for [`io::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html):

```
impl<B: BufRead> Iterator for Lines<B> {
    type Item = Result<String>;
}
```

You cannot use `cloned` because the iterator item is not a reference. You cannot "tell" the compiler otherwise; that's not how types work.

> As I have to iterate at least two times over the lines of the trait `BufRead`, I am cloning the lines of my `BufRead`

That doesn't really make sense. Cloning the lines of the reader wouldn't save anything. In fact, it would probably just make things *worse*. You'd be creating the strings once, not using them except for cloning them, then creating them a third time when you iterate again.

If you wish to avoid recreating all the strings, `collect` all the strings into a `Vec` or other collection and then iterate over that multiple times:

```
pub fn analyze<T: BufRead>(document: T) -> Result<DocumentMetadata, ()> {
    let lines: Result<Vec<_>, _> = document.lines().collect();
    let lines = lines.unwrap();
    let language = guess_language(&lines);

    // Do more lexical analysis based on document language

    Ok(DocumentMetadata {
        language: language,
        // ...
    })
}

fn guess_language<'a, I>(lines: I) -> String 
    where I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a String>,
{
    for line in lines {
        // Try to guess language
    }
    "en".to_string()
}
```

Comment: That makes way more sense, indeed. I was stuck on the idea of cloning the lines because most of the methods of `io::Lines` are consuming the iterator and I didn't think `collect` was adapted to the situation. Thanks!